# SendGrid integration with Firebase trigger email. Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed

Tags: firebase, sendgrid

I have integrated SendGrid Email API with Firebase Trigger Email extension. When I tried to test this integration manually by creating a new document in email_collection in firebase console, I always get this error:

"Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked".

I successfully created an API Key using the SMTP Relay and use it in the SMTP connection URI when configuring the trigger email extension, so I'm not sure if the problem is within SendGrid credentials or in the firebase extension configuration.

[image: This is a screenshot of my SMTP connection URI]

I'm new to this topic, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does your SMTP connection URI look like? (Please share the URI, but mask the password.)

Comment: @philnash I have updated my question by adding the link of the screenshot.

Comment: Can you try port 587 instead? 465 is for SSL, and 587 is for TLS which succeeds SSL and is more secure. Also, can you confirm that the API key you are using there has permission to send emails?

Comment: I tried to use port 587 but it is still not working. And yes, the API Key has permission to send emails.

Comment: I would suggest generating a new API key with send mail permissions and trying that. I can't see anything else wrong here.

Comment: Yes, it works!! It seems that there was an issue with the old API Key. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I recommend you use port 587. While port 465 is available, [SendGrid recommends using port 587](https://sendgrid.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587/).

Other than that, you should check that your API key has permission to send emails. And if it all looks correct, try generating a API key and confirming the permissions.